# ORMlite saving complex database

Tags: android, ormlite

I have a model in the below structure to save it inside the DB using ORMLite

```
class Item {
    String name;
    String number;
    int id
    Detail  detail;
    Category category;// getters and setters   
}
```

And Detail and Category class has

```
class Detail {
    String detailName;
    String detailNumber;
    int id 
    ......
}
```

So now my question is do I need to create Tables in this format

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database,
     ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Item.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Detail.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Category.class);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't create database", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or do i need to have oly Item Table. Actually Item holds all the records all together. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create all the tables as shown in your code snippet. Take a look at the documentation for more [information on ORMLite annotations](http://ormlite.com/docs/annotations).

Comment: do we need to insert all tables seperately or if i set the Item class and update the db means the data will be inserted in its table? Will the Dao will be created by itself for the table or to we need to create each time